# Should I inform company I plan to leave at the end of my contract

Tags: professionalism, resignation, contracts, part-time

I have a contract with a company that ends next month. Since it is temporary contract and not a permanent role do you believe I should inform management that I intend to leave at the end of the contract?

I think could either not say anything since it ends when it ends or perhaps wait and see if they ask to extend contract and then say I decline. I’m just not sure how the best way to go about it is.

Comment: Plan as it will end as agreed upon.  If they approach you with an offer, you can reconsider.

Comment: What does the contract say about notice?

Comment: You mention in a comment below that "they have extended my contract before" - do they wait until the last possible second to do so, or do you typically know some time ahead that they're wanting to extend your contract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't say anything as to whether you will stay or leave.

Ask them, if they have an option so that they can retain you as a permanent employee.

Thus, when you leave at the end of the contract, and if they complain, you can tell them that you already asked them about a permanent position which they didn't offer. So, you will have a moral upperhand.

Comment: What if they offer a permanent position when I don’t want to accept?

Comment: Then you start negoitiating. If negotiation is failed, then they already know that you will be leaving.

Comment: But if they offer job that I refuse do I not lose the moral upper hand?

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia, It depends on the salary and designation. Nothing is written on stones. You have the right to negotiate. If negotiation fails, that is no one's fault. So, yes, you still have the upper hand.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your helpful words.

Comment: Should I ask in advance about permanent position or maybe mention it if they come to me?

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia, nothing will automatically come to you. You have to collect information.

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia, if you really don't want to work in this company no matter what, then you should just keep silent and leave the company quietly. You can just tell them the day before you leave.

Comment: I understand. I just don’t want to leave on bad terms as I’m only young and might need a reference some day.

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia, what is the company's policy in this regard? Does the company want you to give them notice well in advance?

Comment: No. I don’t think I necessarily have to give notice if I leave when the contract ends. But they have extended my contract before so maybe if I left it might surprise them even a little.

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia, So, you have my answer already.

Comment: "But if they offer job that I refuse do I not lose the moral upper hand?" - People all to often misused the concept of morality in order to defend actions.  *Refusing a job offer isn't a question of morality.* Asking if there will be an offer, is simply, a smart decision so you can plan your next move knowing all the facts.  You never know, the company might shock you with their offer, you (literally) can't decline an offer that never comes.  Morality is defined by societies.

Comment: @Donald I just wonder if I should feel bad if they invest time and money into me and then I leave and they need to find someone else.

Comment: @SalvadoPorGracia - It's a temporary role.  They expected you to leave at the end of the contract otherwise it wouldn't have been temporary from the onslaught.